# How to get my AWS CloudFront to serve my website over HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-acm

How can I get a subdomain of my AWS-hosted website (secure.example.com) to use HTTPS only? The domain of my website (example.com) loads HTTPS just fine.

I created an S3 bucket for a subdomain of my website, secure.example.com. I connected it to CloudFront and Route 53. The subdomain now works and you can visit the site in HTTP mode. However, I would like the site to be HTTPS only.

So far, this is what I've done: In ACM, I created a new certificate for the secure.example.com domain. In CloudFront, I set the secure.example.com distribution to use the custom SSL certificate I just created. However, when I go to secure.example.com, it loads as HTTP. If I try to visit https://secure.example.com, the tab spins and never loads.